# Angular code coverage Report for unit and E2E test cases - Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We used Angular5 and CLI to run our project. Currently, I am not able to find an approach which gives me combined code coverage for Unit test cases and E2E test cases.

Unit Test cases: Jasmine
E2E test cases: Protractor.

Is there any way through which I can have both running together?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible.
See: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6286